Is it possible to get the latest branch name for a git commit that is in several branches
I'm trying to get the branch name for a commit in git.
I'm using the following command: 
git name-rev --name-only --always --exclude=tags*  HEAD

but if the commit pointed by HEAD contains several branches how can I get the latest that was created from that specific commit
For example, this is the first line of git log command: 
commit 4126555537691488d316d911dd881f0haf64ddbe (HEAD, origin/stage, origin/develop, origin/HEAD, stage, develop) 
the git name-rev command above always, returns develop, why ?
Can I get all the branches ? can I have a sorted list, somehow ?
I also tried to use git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
I would like to add the branch name to a version string, so I will know from which branch the code was built.
The issue is that when I branch out from my development branch, i.e. develop, to a different branch, and did not commit anything yet to the 2nd branch I get only develop although I checked out to stage, e.g. 
git checkout stage
git name-rev --name-only --always --exclude=tags*  HEAD

the result is develop
Thanks.

To print all branches pointing at HEAD, you can use git for-each-ref refs/heads --point-at HEAD. But, there is no "the latest branch".

Branch is a name and a pointer to a commit. Branches itself don't have timestamps. What is "the latest branch" then? A branch that was created later? Git doesn't store that information. "The latest" could be a branch that point to the latest commit. Is it what you want?

The problem is that I checkout branch name stage but the result that I get is develop and not the right branch name.

There're many ways to get the current branch name. In case there're more then 1 branch pointing to the current commit some commands return different names. Most probably you're looking for git branch --show-current. See my script.

this does not work if I checkout a commit

@sagi In detached HEAD there is no "current branch" (my script demonstares that if checkout @~). What branch do you want instead if there're many branches pointing to the commit considering that all branches are equal and Git doesn't store much info for branches beyond their names and head commits? You can try to parse git reflog to find out branches.

thanks, will check. But there are 2 issues here, the first is that I checked-out a specific branch pointing to a same commit as another branch, but with the name-rev I get the other branch name. The 2nd issue , is that I would like to get a branch name for a detached head, to find to what branches it belongs

In detached HEAD you cannot get a branch if there're many. You can list branches with git branch --points-at=HEAD but if you want a branch you're free to select one at random. Most probably it's what git name-rev does. git reflog -> " checkout: moving from master to @~"; parse that and get master as the previous branch.
